# Finder application window without with the minimize icon disabled

Tags: finder, windows, dock, icon

I noticed that sometimes, mostly after a restart, the window of my finder application has the minimize icon disabled like this:

[image: minimize icon]

I can't click on it, and I have to close and reopen the window in order to make it clickable. Bug or feature?